# FFMPEG: 2x2 Grid Cameras stream to Youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, stream, grid

So this is my "working" ffmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "input1" -rtsp_transport tcp -i "input2" -rtsp_transport tcp -i "input3" -rtsp_transport tcp -i "input4" -filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=480x270 [a0];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=480x270 [a1];[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=480x270 [a2];[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=480x270 [a3];[a0][a1][a2][a3]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|0_h0|w0_0|w0_h0[out]" -map "[out]" -map 3:a -video_size 1920x1080 -tune zerolatency -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -b:v 5000k -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -q:v 3 -crf 15 -r 15 -c:a aac -ac 2 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/...`

The problem that i have is that the Youtube recognize this stream as only "360p" and i think that the quality of each stream is way worst than these cameras really are.

Is there something that i'm doing wrong or it should "work" like that because of scalling it to 2x2 grid?

Comment: Four videos scaled to 480x270 and stacked in 2x2 will result in a 960x540 output. Don't downscale them.

Comment: What do you mean? How did i downscale them?

Comment: @Martin With `scale=480x270`, assuming the inputs are larger than 480x270. You should always include the complete log from the command so we don't have to make assumptions. Also, `-video_size 1920x1080` is not a valid output option for your encoder/muxer and is being ignored.

Comment: Sorry im not that familiar with these things, could you tell me how to show the full log?

With these scalling i was just trying to fit all four cameras exactly in one screen and it looks pretty good, no borders or smth. So what scale should i set? i thought that 480x270 with four videos will result in one big screen with 1920x1080?

Comment: The "log" is just the text that ffmpeg spews out in the terminal/console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each video should take up half the width and half the height, so 960x540:

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "input1" -rtsp_transport tcp -i "input2" -rtsp_transport tcp -i "input3" -rtsp_transport tcp -i "input4" -filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540 [a0];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540 [a1];[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540 [a2];[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540 [a3];[a0][a1][a2][a3]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|0_h0|w0_0|w0_h0,format=yuv420p[out]" -map "[out]" -map 3:a -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune zerolatency -b:v 5000k -maxrate 5000k -bufsize 10000k -r 15 -c:a aac -ac 2 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/`

Unrelated changes:

- Removed `-video_size 1920x1080` as this is being ignored because it is generally an input option for certain demuxers.
- Removed `-q:v 3` because libx264 ignores `-q:v`. Use `-crf` or `-b:v` instead.
- Removed `-crf 15` because it is mutually exclusive with `-b:v`. This means you can only use one at a time. If you use both then one will get ignored. For streaming you should use `-b:v` instead of `-crf` unless you know what you're doing.
- Removed `-level 3.0`. Level 3.0 is too low for 1920x1080 (libx264 will tell you this in the log output with a "level limit" warning). You shouldn't need to limit the level anyway.
- Removed `-profile:v baseline`. No need to target devices from 2008.
- Added format filter `format=yuv420p` so the output is always YUV 4:2:0 for chroma subsampling.
- Added `-bufsize` and `-maxrate` to enable VBV which is highly recommended for streaming.

Comment: Thanks a lot @llogan AGAIN! :) Almost everything works great, you are as always much helpful!